# client-service architecture: keep client in sync with in-memory data sctructure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, architecture, websocket, redis

I have a service that updates a set in **redis** (fast in-memory data storage) in the real time. 
I also have a **rails** app that is connected to this redis instance. The task is to display the set contents to all the clients. Please note that according to some client's settings, some elements of the set are not supposed to be sent to them.

I don't want to send the whole set contents on every update. It should be possible to only send diff, and I'm choosing which approach to use.

implementation of *rails -> client* connection:

- **react** - react sounds like a good fit for maintaining the real time state. If I make props updating in the real time, the html will be kept up to date for free.
- **actioncable** - there is a component in newest rails that integrates websockets into rails app.

*service -> redis set -> rails*:

- I could use **pub/sub redis** feature and make the service that writes to redis set send the elements that are changed/updated/deleted in the set, and then use the set itself only to send data to the new clients, and the existing ones will be kept in sync via pub/sub. So, to update a client, the following is performed:

  1. the service is about to update element in the set
  2. the service adds the element to the set in redis
  3. the service sends the element to the pub/sub queue
  4. rails app, being subscribed to the pub/sub queue, receives the element
  5. rails app filters the list of clients to see which ones should get the update (normally, it's most of them)
  6. rails app broadcasts the new item, and the clients render it

On top of that, I'll also have to implement change/delete cases.
It seems like this approach is way too complex and low-level. Things can easily get out of sync, and they are duplicated in memory several times.

- instead of **pub/sub** I can make rails app read redis set contents repeatedly and compute if any changes occured. It should be cheap as redis stores the set in memory. If rails app detects a change, it broadcasts it to the client. Still, it feels wrong to have to check if something has changed in memory based on a timeout.

Additional info: there will not be too many clients, maybe a thousand. The set will be updated once per second, sometimes more, sometimes less.

What will be the best approach to keep clients in sync with the state in redis? Is react usage justified? Is there some native react implementation of such "diff" pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I have an app that is using both React and ActionCables.

The two work fairly well together.  It's important to realize the limitations of ActionCables (it has a lower user limit benchmark than other similar tools), but if you aren't expecting thousands of users to be using it simultaneously, it works just fine.

Whether or not you use React, I think a Flux pattern goes a long way towards managing the state of socket connections.  Both Vanilla Flux and Redux are great companions, and do a wonderful job of listening to changes from the server and then disseminating that information out to relevant areas of your application.  They both happen to be intended foremost for use with React, but in reality you could use them with any frontend framework.

Comment: Will flux also take care of _only syncing the changes_? Or should I do that myself (e.g. messages like "element with index 1 updated - element with index 4 deleted - new element 10)?

Comment: Usually the best way to handle that within Flux is to have the data in your store saved as an object with key/value pairs equivalent to `id` and your model.  Then you use `Object.assign` or jquery's `$.extend` to merge new items into the object, or just `delete state[2]` to delete an item (in this case, the one with id = 2).